# Andriod device rebooting constantly

Tags: factory-reset, unbricking, reboot, partitions

Because of processes stoped working and fixing them was taking too long with 0 rezults I tryed to reset it to factory settings but that didn't work so I also wiped the cache and media patitions and now it's in a constant rebooting state. I doesn't even load the OS just shows a logo and a loading screen with images like this one: [link](http://s1.emagst.net/products/411/410541/media/res_b6552f64fc00b1ec9559e8d6bf9a38db.png).

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The steps below will walk you through clearing the partition on your device.

This process will not delete any information from your device.

1.  Power up the phone by pressing the VOL UP + VOL DOWN KEY together + POWER KEY .

2.  The device will enumerate with different BOOT OPTIONS

3.  Use the VOL DOWN Key to SCROLL and VOL UP Key to SELECT

4.  Select Recovery

5.  The device will start up, now power up to  a little Android man logo with Exclamation mark

6.  Press the VOL UP and VOL DOWN Key together at this screen

7.  The device will display BLUE Text on a Black background .

1. Use the VOL DOWN Key to scroll DOWN and the POWER Key to SELECT the option desired .
2. In this case , press the VOL DOWN key till the cache partition wipe is selected and press the POWER key to confirm the selection .
3. Use the VOL DOWN key again to select YES - delete all user data and press the POWER key to CONFIRM .
4. The device will then start performing the partition wipe
5. Once the Formatting is complete , press the POWER key to confirm a REBOOT
6. The message rebooting is displayed on the phone.
7. The device will reboot and start the normal power up sequence .

Comment: Already did that, that is the cause of my problem

Comment: which rom did u try and from where did u download the rom files? which version of android was that?

Comment: I have jellybean and didn't download anything, just wiped the 2 partitons and then choose factory reset. I dont have a rocovery option. The tablet is AllView City+

Comment: seems like the action you performed corrupted your OS. you probably need to reinstall your OS. have a look on [this link](http://www.mygadgetsinfo.com/2012/08/free-download-android-os-411-jelly-bean.html) this will help you to download and install a new OS jelly bean 4.1 . this might solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

May be it got stuck in boot loop.

You can recover your phone. Search the internet, preferably XDA forum, for your phone model. They will surely help you.

Comment: "Search the Internet" is not really an answer.